# how to reduce size of checkbox and radio button in office ui fabric

Tags: css, html, office-ui-fabric

I am developing a web-app add-in for Microsoft office online. I am using http://dev.office.com/fabric/components/choicefield radio and checkbox button as shown in the link.

how to reduce the size of these control basically radio and checkbox.These controls size is bigger than what i expect.

Answer (score 2):

If using UI Fabric React, you can style the checkboxes directly by using the api, for example:

```
render() {
  const styles = {
    checkbox: {
      width: "16px",
      height: "16px"
    }
  }

  return <Checkbox
    label="Checkbox"
    styles={styles}
  />
}
```

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/checkbox#implementation

Answer (score 0):

In the *ChoiceField.css* the related rules to these controls are the following ones; Change the **width** and **height** to *size* them and **left** and **top** to *center* the **:checked** states.

**Radio Button**:

```
.ms-ChoiceField-input:checked + .ms-ChoiceField-field:before {
  background-color: #666666;
  border-color: #666666;
  color: #666666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '\00a0';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ms-ChoiceField-field:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px #c8c8c8 solid;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Ckeckbox**:

```
.ms-ChoiceField-input[type='checkbox']:checked + .ms-ChoiceField-field:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Office365Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  speak: none;
  content: '\e041';
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}

.ms-ChoiceField-field:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px #c8c8c8 solid;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```